# How to extract at runtime the AST or the bytecode or anything that uniquelly, deterministically and universally identifies a function* in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have managed to do it in Python, since the interpreter provide the bytecodes, as shown below.
From the bytecodes it was easy to apply a hashing function.

```
import dis
from inspect import signature

# Add signature.
fargs = list(signature(f).parameters.keys())
if not fargs:
    raise Exception(f"Missing function input parameters.")
clean = [fargs]

# Clean line numbers.
groups = [l for l in dis.Bytecode(f).dis().split("\n\n") if l]
for group in groups:
    lines = [segment for segment in group.split(" ") if segment][1:]
    clean.append(lines)
```

How could I extract a similar kind of *deterministic* *universally* *unique* ¹ function identifier in Haskell?
Are there built-in libraries or GHC extensions for that?

`1 -` *unique*, probabilistically speaking

`* -` A *function* not in the math sense, since the possibilities to check programatically the equivalence of programs are very limited. So I am only interested in what is possible and costless attainable, i.e., generate a unique identity for functions with the exact same code (or bytecode, to avoid formatting noise). In my specific use case, even the signatures and parameter names should match, but that is not relevant for the point here, which is about how to inspect Haskell code at runtime.

Comment: Pretty certain this is deliberately not possible at runtime.

Comment: What do you want it to do with non-static functions like `(+n)` where `n` is something bound in the environment that came from user input? Given that Haskell allows creating arbitrarily complex function values at runtime, this seems like an important detail. One that your python code appears to omit, too. It's less common in python, but it can be done.

Comment: If you only care about things that exist statically, https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/static_pointers.html might be interesting. Though it only works within/between instances of the same program.

Comment: Is `\x -> x + 1` to be identified as uniquely distinct from `\y -> 1 + y` to be uniquely distinct from `(+ 1)` from `(1 +)`? Why? If I just declared four functions to be those four expressions would that make them distinct? Why? And parallel q's for Python -- which has lambdas.

Comment: of course Python doesn't pretend to be referentially transparent and stuff, so it makes no attempt to ensure that `lambda x: x+1` and `lambda y: 1+y` are counted as the same function. But Haskell does...

Comment: @LouisWasserman Why would it be deliberately not possible at runtime? Would it break typing, state management or any principle in Haskell?

Comment: Referential transparency would be broken, as alluded to in @user253751's comment.  If two functions always have the same results -- even if their implementations are completely different -- then any operation on them should have the exact same result.  If you can inspect their implementations, than that inspection is an operation with two different results.  `\x -> x+1` and `\y -> y+1` is a trivial example, but there are many problems with very different algorithms that it'd require a proof to demonstrate the equivalence of.

Comment: @Carl External references can stay just as references by name. Ideally they would be replaced by value, but is not needed if it is impossible. The expected functions are not intended to depend on external arbitrary values. They can rely on references, provided they are guaranteed by the user to be always the same, like calling a function from a specific version of a library. Thanks for the link for Static, seems a possibility.

Comment: @AntC What is impossibible to assess programatically can be ignored. My focus is on being certain when I say `a=b`. When the comparison returns a possible `a!=b` (which actually means "I don't know"), that doesn't have to be true, in my use case.

Comment: @user253751 That is good point. Probably in Haskell I cannot rely on inspecting the function signature, at least for the parameter names.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If I understood correctly, the runtime will have a single 'compiled/bytecode' function for both source codes, so it cannot stablish a 1-to-1 relationship. Otherwise the inspection would need to return a list of source codes. Ok, having the same bytecode for meny functions is even better for me, since the more cases I can detect equality of functions the better. Even losing the original identifiers, I'm still interested in that 'bytecode' living in the runtime.

Comment: @LouisWasserman However, GHC can change implementation in a way that changes the bytecode, and that's ok for me, but I suppose that's not tolerable if one expects the bytecode to be within the referential transparency framework, when one calls e.g. `get_bytecode(f)` across diferent GHC versions. I am not sure ref. transp. applies to different compiler versions or program executions.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Now I understood...  You're saying that `get_bytecode(f) /= get_bytecode(g)` but `f = g`. Well, mathematically, i.e. considering the operation happens over abstract funtions `f`and `g`, it can be ugly, but if we consider the operation is applied on their implementations, that's ok.

Comment: Haskell's definition of referential transparency cares about the functions' behavior, not implementations.  As a result, it would violate Haskell's referential transparency to support such an operation.

Comment: But @LouisWasserman do note that Haskell has such functions anyway, because they are useful in reality outside of mathematical la-la land. For example `unsafePerformIO` should be well-known by now.

Comment: @user253751 but `unsafePerformIO` is not really part of Haskell. It's part of the FFI which GHC provides to link Haskell to other languages. Of course, GHC also provides things like [`reallyUnsafePtrEquality#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:reallyUnsafePtrEquality-35-)...

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes so the point is that Haskell implementations do provide things that aren't "proper" Haskell but are useful for various internal/debugging/implementation-specific/other strange purposes. Debug.Trace is another one. Anything involving "bytecode" certainly falls in this category.

Comment: user253751 @LouisWasserman leftaroundabout Thanks for the insightful comments! Perhaps there is some language today or in the future able to provide deterministic ids for "functions" by design. It seems compelling nowadays.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I disagree that `unsafePerformIO` is just part of the FFI. I think it's an important "escape hatch" for certain sorts of library programming (e.g., pure parallel programming).

Answer (score 1):

Within a single run of the program, you might consider `StableName`. You can make a `StableName` for any value (including a function/closure), get a hash value for a `StableName`, and compare two `StableName`s for equality. If two things have the same `StableName`, then they're definitely the same. If they have the same `StableName` hash, then they're probably the same. Note that if you just need to be able to check equality and don't need the hashes, one option is `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#`, which just compares any two values by address.